# THREE.js Reusing geometry does not seem to work efficiently

Tags: performance, memory-management, geometry, three.js

I am loading several models into scene using the same geometry like so (pseudo code):

```
var geoCache = [];

function parseJSONGeometry(json_geo){
  // this code is the three.js model parser from the jsonloader
  return geometry;
}

function loadCachedGeo(data){
  if( !geoCache[data.id] ){
    geoCache[json.id] = parseJSONGeometry(data);
  }
  return geoCache[json.id]; 
}

function loadObjects(json){
  var mats = []; 
  combined = new THREE.Geometry();
  for(i=0<i<json.geometries.length;i++){
    data = json.geometries[i];
    geo = loadCachedGeo(data.id);
    mats.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(map:THREE.imageUtils.loadTexture(data.src)));
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo);
    mesh.position.set(data.x,data.y,data.z);
    combined = THREE.GeometryUtils.mergeGeometry(combined,mesh);
  }
  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(combined,new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(mats));
  scene.add(mesh);
}
```

I also cache the textures, however I omitted that for the sake of simplicity.

When I call:

```
renderer.info.render.faces
renderer.info.memory.textures
renderer.info.memory.programs
renderer.info.memory.geometries;
renderer.info.render.calls
```

I notice when one object is on the screen the poly count is say 1000, textures: 1, calls:  1, shaders: 1 and geometries: 1. When two objects are on the screen 2000 faces are reported, 1 texture, 1 shader, 2 calls, and 2 geometries.

I thought that reusing geometry in this fashion only loads the geometry once into the gpu. Am I missing something, can someone PLEASE explain this behavior?

Three.js r59

Answer (score 0):

You need to inspect

```
renderer.info.memory.geometries
```

There is also

```
renderer.info.memory.textures
renderer.info.memory.programs
```

three.js r.59

Comment: I use those also, should I not be concerned about the poly (face) count?

Comment: Your question was about reusing geometry. You should see that the rederer is doing that. The face count is a different issue.

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand your comment; are the faces not part of the geometry?

Comment: Have a look at `WebGLRenderer.renderBuffer()` so you understand what is going on. `renderer.info.render.faces` is just the number of triangles being rendered in your scene. If you are sharing geometries, VBOs are being reused.

Comment: Ah, ok. So even if the geometry is reused, the renderer will still show independent faces/verts?

Comment: I created a test environment. The amount og geometries goes up for every new mesh even though I am using the above method to re-use gemetries. Textures are fine, shaders are fine. I edited the original question to include this information.